What is the name of this object: given k, $n = \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{b_i}{i}$
My teacher gave me an assignment on what she calls the k-binomial form of natural numbers. I couldn't find any further information by googling, so I'm asking here. Let me state all that I know about this mathematical object:
Description
Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. For any integer $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the $k$-binomial form of $n$ is:
$$n = \binom{b_1}{1} + \binom{b_2}{2} + ... + \binom{b_k}{k}$$
or equivalently
$$n = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \binom{b_i}{i}$$
in which $b_1<b_2<...<b_k$ is a sequence of natural numbers.
It is easy to prove that for a given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists only one such sequence $(b_i)$.
This leads to some interesting results which might have something to do with number theory. Here's a few examples.
$$0 = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \binom{i-1}{i}$$
$$1 = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \binom{i-1}{i} + \binom{k}{k}$$
More generally, if $0 \le n \le k$, we have
$$n = \sum_{i=1}^{k-n} \binom{i-1}{i} + \sum_{i=k-n+1}^{k} \binom{i}{i}$$
$$k + 1 = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \binom{i-1}{i} + \binom{k+1}{k}$$
Let us write $n \equiv a_1,a_2,...,a_k$ to state $n = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \binom{i-1+a_i}{i}$. Let $k = 3$. Then:

$0 \equiv 0,0,0$
$1 \equiv 0,0,1$
$2 \equiv 0,1,1$
$3 \equiv 1,1,1$
$4 \equiv 0,0,2$
$5 \equiv 0,1,2$
$6 \equiv 1,1,2$
$7 \equiv 0,2,2$
$8 \equiv 1,2,2$
$9 \equiv 2,2,2$
$10 \equiv 0,0,3$
...

Questions
What is the common name for this kind of objects?
This looks like some kind of base-3 numbering system. This looks related to number theory. Is it ? Do you know other number systems which "count" in a similar fashion?

I guess the notation I used is a bit confusing. We always have $b_i < b_{i+1}$. However, when I say $n \equiv a_1,a_2,...,a_k$, this means $b_i = i - 1 + a_i$, not $b_i = a_i$.

Can you edit the writeup to include ^ in the relevant section? It can be a bit confusing to read as you suddenly switched to $a_i$ without explaining what it is. $\quad$ There is a pattern (hopefully obvious) to what the $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_k$ form is. Can you identify it and explain why we have that pattern?

This is also called the combinatorial number system, or combinadics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system

The name is combinatorial number system or combinadics.
Thanks Mike Earnest for the answer.
